# Call extension function IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, button, call

How can I call extension function, so that the button is encouraged to call the view.
I made a UiButton Extension with a function to animate a button, and everything works, but only if I call it from:

```
@IBAction func botonVuelta(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.pulsarAnimacion()
}
```

but if you called it from viewDidLoad it doesn’t work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    botones.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    botones.pulsarAnimacion()
}
```

I’d appreciate it if you could give me a solution,
I thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is a very early place to animate a view , try inside

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     botones.pulsarAnimacion()
}
```